# Trying to load webpage using OpenUrl package in nodejs using setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, setinterval

I am new to NodeJS, I have a microservice running which I want to open a webpage without a browser, to make client side api requests every 20 seconds. I am attempting to use the package openurl

```
const openPage = require("openurl");

function openUpPage(url){
   openPage.open(url);
}

setInterval(function() { openUpPage("myURl") }, 20000);
```

However I now keep getting the error:

```
events.js:183
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: spawn xdg-open ENOENT
at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit ( 
internal/child_process.js:190:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Comment: So you don't want to open browser but still you use a module that is specifically for opening a browser. That doesn't make any sense. To make an api request you better use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: This is XY problem. The actual solution depends on your *real problem*, not on expected solution, which was wrong.

Comment: @Molda Does openurl not use the operating system?

Comment: @Daniel it does use OS to open a browser at the given url.